# subtracting files with same final formate

Tags: python

I have done code to subtract three diffenert input files that conist from string and float with text format.
I am having issue that the final file format is not the same as the input file format as shown below although the code is working

```
def safeFloat(word):
    try:
        return float(word)
    except ValueError:
        return False

def is_float(element: any) -> bool:
    try:
        float(element)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open('CHGCAR1.txt', 'r') as f:
  CHGCAR1 = f.read()
  CHGCAR1_ints = [safeFloat(x) for x in CHGCAR1.split()]
  print(CHGCAR1_ints)
  CHGCAR1_ints_1 = [c for c in CHGCAR1_ints if c is not None]
  print(CHGCAR1_ints_1)

with open('CHGCAR2.txt', 'r') as f:
  CHGCAR2 = f.read()
  CHGCAR2_ints = [safeFloat(x) for x in CHGCAR2.split()]
  print(CHGCAR2_ints)
  CHGCAR2_ints_2 = [c for c in CHGCAR2_ints if c is not None]
  print(CHGCAR2_ints_2)
with open('CHGCAR3.txt', 'r') as f:
  CHGCAR3 = f.read()
  CHGCAR3_ints = [safeFloat(x) for x in CHGCAR3.split()]
  print(CHGCAR3_ints)
  CHGCAR3_ints_3 = [c for c in CHGCAR3_ints if c is not None]
  print(CHGCAR3_ints_3)
  
with open("CHGCAR_final.txt", 'w') as f:
    for i in range( min( len(CHGCAR1_ints_1), len(CHGCAR2_ints_2), len(CHGCAR3_ints_3)) ) :
        f.write(str(CHGCAR1_ints_1[i] - CHGCAR2_ints_2[i] - CHGCAR3_ints_3[i]))
        f.write(' ')
```

Comment: Are you sure that the range specification is really what you want? Perhaps you could provide some sample input and expected output

Comment: Yes,  the input and output are numbers with some words

Comment: Please edit your question to include a copy/paste of an example input and the output that goes with it.  It would also help if you showed what you want the output to look like.